# Replacing part of a Pandas Dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I have a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create data
name  = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
data  = np.random.rand(9)
label = ['squirrel']*9

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name,
                   'Data': data,
                  'label': label})

"""
Produces:
    Name      Data     label
0      0  0.518886  squirrel
1      0  0.167908  squirrel
2      0  0.918280  squirrel
3      1  0.027823  squirrel
4      1  0.392099  squirrel
5      1  0.724943  squirrel
6      2  0.480646  squirrel
7      2  0.737251  squirrel
8      2  0.212135  squirrel
"""
```

I have another array of length 3, say `new_array = 10*np.ones(3)`. How can I replace the values in the `Data` column with the new array, for the rows where `Name = 1`? The ideal result would be:

```
    Name      Data     label
0      0  0.518886  squirrel
1      0  0.167908  squirrel
2      0  0.918280  squirrel
3      1  10.00000  squirrel
4      1  10.00000  squirrel
5      1  10.00000  squirrel
6      2  0.480646  squirrel
7      2  0.737251  squirrel
8      2  0.212135  squirrel
```

I've tried isolating the dataframe where `Name = 1`, and setting those values equal to the new array:

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == '1']['Data'] = new_array
```

Additionally, I've also looked at [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), and looked into `.loc`, `.iloc`, and `.ix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df['Name']==1,['Data']]=new_array
```

Output:

```
   Name Data        label
0   0   0.587762    squirrel
1   0   0.612776    squirrel
2   0   0.098259    squirrel
3   1   10.000000   squirrel
4   1   10.000000   squirrel
5   1   10.000000   squirrel
6   2   0.180574    squirrel
7   2   0.782238    squirrel
8   2   0.777101    squirrel
```

---

**Explanation:**

using `loc` you select those values ​​in the `Data` column for the `rows` where `df ['Name'] == 1`

**Note:**

keep in mind that the rest of the values ​​are not the same as in your example since they are randomly generated numbers.